# Error Deploying Docker Container to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a Docker Image I've created.  I created a .zip file with a Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json file.

When I deploy, I get the following error:

```
[2015-11-02T18:08:30.366Z] ERROR [4515]  : Command execution failed: Activity failed. (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError) caused by: jq: error: Cannot iterate over null ab6ac43aeaf75fb000d02a1fee73e829a92cef629bad46e6b727dc967f837b54
Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Mon Nov  2 18:08:30 UTC 2015:. Check snapshot logs for details. (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError) caused by: jq: error: Cannot iterate over null ab6ac43aeaf75fb000d02a1fee73e829a92cef629bad46e6b727dc967f837b54
Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Mon Nov  2 18:08:30 UTC 2015:. Check snapshot logs for details. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
[2015-11-02T18:08:30.366Z] ERROR [4515]  : Command CMD-Startup(stage 1) failed!
```

What's odd is that when I use elastic beanstalk CLI to deploy locally, it works fine.  Any ideas on what could be happening here?

Comment: Maybe *Check snapshot logs for details*? ;)

Comment: I got these lines from the logs.

Comment: Could you append here your Dockerrunfile?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add the following bit to your **Dockerrun.aws.json** file to get past this issue.

```
"Volumes": []
```